# Is "$onInit", more efficient way than "activate" to activate "controller" in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-compile, angularjs-lifecycle

I'm new to angularJS and want to implement the efficient thing for my project but got stuck between `$onInit` ([life cycle hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#life-cycle-hooks)) and `activate()`.

Comment: The question would be clearer if you cite the style guide that recommends using an `activate()` method. The use of `activate()` is a matter of opinion as it is a style recommended by some *opinionated* style guides. The AngularJS $compile service invokes the `$onInit` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) after it binds attributes to the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an `activate()` function inside of your controller and calling it directly is quite different than using the `$onInit()` lifecycle hook provided by AngularJS.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture:

> `$onInit()` - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

So basically the `activate()` function will be called as soon as your controller is constructed.  Where as the `$onInit()` function will be called **after** all bindings have be successfully bound.  Thus if you try to access your bound variables within your constructor, they will not be initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `activate()` is a matter of opinion as it is a style recommended by some *opinionated* style guides.

On the other hand, the `$onInit` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) is invoked by the `$compile` service.

From the Docs:

> ## Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onInit()` - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.
>
> — [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)